# how disable DrawerArrowToggle from toolbar or move right

Tags: android, toolbar, right-to-left

first question:
 i want to create a right to left toolbar like this image:

[image: right to left toolbar]

how can customize the toolbar DrawerArrowToggle  to move right?

And second question:
i create a custom toolbar and make a button for open drawer but toolbar DrawerArrowToggle   is appear left of my custom toolbar. 
[image]
how to remove it?

**--update--**

with thanks to [sasikumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3710865/sasikumar) by adding this line the DrawerArrowToggle is removed.

```
mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
```

here my toolbar code:

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_bar, null);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    actionBar.setCustomView(view, new ActionBar.LayoutParams
            (ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    Toolbar parent = (Toolbar) view.getParent();
    parent.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0);



Drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, Drawer,
            parent, R.string.openDrawer,
            R.string.closeDrawer) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);


        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            if (item != null && item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
                if (Drawer.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
                    Drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                } else {
                    Drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
    Drawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
```

my desire app is like this:
[image: sample right to left toolbar]

sorry for bad english.

Comment: so you have an arabic app?

Comment: @HawraaKhalil no that's a Persian app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can hide the arrow by using onDrawerSlide method.

```
drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,
    getToolbar(), R.string.open, R.string.close) {

@Override
public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
    super.onDrawerClosed(view);
}

@Override
public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
    super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
}
 @Override
public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
    super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, 0); // this disables the animation 
}
};
```

If you want to remove the arrow completely, you can add

```
super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, 0); // this disables the arrow @ completed state
```

at the end of the onDrawerOpened function

Comment: i add _super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, 0);_ at end of onDrawerOpened.  but the ActionBarDrawerToggle is showing ...

Comment: add this code mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);

Comment: Thanks. the DrawerArrowToggle is removed by adding _mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);_

Answer (score 1):

Check the below link, maybe helpful:

[How can I open navigation drawer from right side to left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17852091/how-can-i-open-navigation-drawer-from-right-side-to-left)

and this link too:

[Android - Is Navigation Drawer from right hand side possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156340/android-is-navigation-drawer-from-right-hand-side-possible)

Comment: thanks for answer. but my problem is moving ActionBarDrawerToggle to right (image that open navigation drawer) Or complete remove that from toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you've added remaining code.Simply set your drawer component gravity to the right.
like...

`android:layout_gravity="right"`

now set the drawer position to the right using following code:

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, 
        R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, 
        R.string.drawer_close) { 

    @Override 
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item != null && item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
            } else { 
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
            } 
        } 
        return false; 
    } 
};
```

Comment: thanks for answer. but how to move DrawerArrowToggle (hamburger icon) to right of toolbar?

Comment: May be you can use **ActionItems** and open and close the drawer on the click of that.