# Android NavigationView from right side

Tags: android, navigationview, side-menu

I have created an Android application, in that I want to open slide menu from right side and when drawer is open I want to slide the view like attached image.

[image]

Code:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start">


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView_Right_Home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
         android:fitsSystemWindows="true"  />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

For slide view I have used below code, but it's not working

```
        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            View container = findViewById(R.id.ll);
            float moveFactor = (slideOffset - drawerView.getWidth());

            container.setTranslationX(moveFactor);

            drawer.bringChildToFront(drawerView);
            drawer.requestLayout();
        }
```

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32439171/how-to-implement-drawer-menu-open-from-right-side

Comment: @sasikumar, I am able to open menu from right side, but I also want to slide view like attached image.

Comment: If I'm following you correctly, the translation - your `moveFactor` - would be `-drawerView.getWidth() * slideOffset`. The `slideOffset` is a fraction that ranges from `0f` to `1f`, not the actual width of anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To slide the `View` to the left with the drawer, your `moveFactor` would be as follows:

```
float moveFactor = -drawerView.getWidth() * slideOffset;
```

Do note the negative sign in front of `drawerView.getWidth()`.

The `slideOffset` is a fraction that ranges from `0f` to `1f`. Multiplying that by the drawer's width gives the actual offset, and negating it, we translate the content `View` to the left.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
float moveFactor = drawerView.getWidth() * slideOffset;
container.setTranslationX(moveFactor);
```

Comment: It slides view to right side, I want to slide view to left side.